# Select data in many to many relationship in Linq

Tags: linq, poco

I have a linq query problem.
My models;

```
public class Product : Entity
{
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    //etc...

    public virtual ICollection<ProductProductShowcase> ProductProductShowcases { get; set;}    
}

public class ProductShowcase : ContextContainer<ProductShowcaseContext>
{
    public virtual ICollection<ProductProductShowcase> ProductProductShowcases { get; set; }
}

public class ProductProductShowcase : Entity
{
    public int ProductShowcaseId  { get; set; }

    public int ProductId  { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductShowcase ProductShowcase  { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product  { get; set; }
}
```

I want to select `ProductShowcase` entities with related **products**. I tried;

```
ProductShowcase productShowcase = RepositoryHelper.DataContext.ProductShowcases.Include(i => i.Contexts).Include(o => o.ProductProductShowcases).Where(o => o.Id == Id).SingleOrDefault();
```

In query result `productShowcase.ProductProductShowcases` has `ProductId` properties with expected values but `Product` properties as null.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Product` property is marked as virtual so lazy loading will be used. If you want it to be populated on the initial query you can use `Include(o => o.Product)` ( you already use Include on the `ProductProductShowcases` property.)

Comment: yes but the problem is Product objects are null in productShowcase.ProductProductShowcases collection. So i need to include ProductProductShwcase.Product but i couldn't figured it out how.